# Deep customize Allure report pages

Tags: python, allure

I am looking at the docs, and I can't get any progress in customizing the allure report.

I do generate the report using the python version of the allure tool. the output is nice, but it is the default one, and I can't find a way to make changes to the standard UI.

I did find some examples online, where the reports are quite different from the default that I get, and I can't figure out exactly how did they customize the reports. The manual online does specify how to add various elements to the report, like steps, attachments, but not much about how do you modify the pages, generated from the XML output file, by the allure tool.

Is this even possible or is a limitation of the allure python tool?

Due to the lack of progress, I am seriously thinking to look elsewhere and find a different reporting framework; although I like Allure since it integrate into py.test seamlessly with few decorators (and most of the frameworks that I did find, look like they were made in the 90s and mostly for Java).

Comment: Could you please also describe the changes you want to add to the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In allure 2 was planned pluginization for change default view of results. Now it is in beta, but still hasn't any docs about api. Maybe some features that you want is ready, otherwise you can contribuite to project. Please, explain what kind of features you need [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2)  or [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python2) and we try to help you.

Comment: Some plugin examples you can find here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/tree/master/plugins

Comment: Very useful, thanks for the update! In particular, I am trying to customize the front page report (the first one opened; getting some graphs from the "graph" section, and getting some history of previous tests run. At the moment I have no way to do so; unless I modify the pages after they get created, which is not really ideal

Comment: Also do you have plans to update the python tools? I see that Java seems to be the preferred language, although I did not find a lot related to python, beside the github page with the bindings. Thanks!

Comment: Historic info already implemented in allure2. Also we have thrend graph in overview tab. Try it with last beta.

Comment: First beta is available on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/allure-pytest/2.0.0b1) for [python](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python2)

Comment: @DmitryBaev I would like to use Allure for large scale testing as a centralized point for monitoring and management but it lacks some feature I badly need. E.g. I would like to see the Trend of a certain test case for each build, or another feature could be showing **values** (_not statuses e.g. passed/failed_) for performance tests and have their historic info from build to build. Are such kind of features coming in the near future or do I have to write a plugin on my own?

Comment: Check out Allure EE, it may perfectly meet your needs https://qameta.io